# An example in Yet Another Haskell Tutorial

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.
In Yet Another Haskell Tutorial, page *Type Basics*, I find this example:

```
count2 bTest list = foldr (\x cnt -> if bTest x then cnt+1 else cnt) 0 list
```

but I think that the lambda function

```
\x cnt -> if bTest x then cnt+1 else cnt
```

is not a pure function, given that its behavior depends on something external to the function, namely the function `bTest`. Is this correct?

Comment: In Haskell all functions are pure. You can not define this lambda expression at the upper level, since there `bTest` is unknown. It is thus a function that behaves differently based on the first parameter of `count2`.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "closure" - a function that references a value outside its own scope. That's not at all the same as being impure, since like all values in Haskell, the closed-over ones must be immutable.

Comment: Note that pretty much the same reasoning applies to the use of `foldr` in the definition of `count2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda abstractions are expressions which denote function values, much like arithmetic expressions denote numeric values. Both kinds of expressions might refer to variables defined elsewhere, and this does not break "purity"/referential transparency.

The value of the arithmetic expression

```
2*x + 1
```

depends on the value of `x`, but that does not make the above code "impure". Consider the function

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = 2*x + 1
```

This produces the same output value for the same input value, so it it pure.

Now, consider the lambda expression

```
\y -> 2*x + y
```

This denotes a function value which depends on `x`, much like the arithmetic expression depends on `x`. There's no difference in this regard.

Indeed, the function

```
g :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
g x = \y -> 2*x + y
```

is pure: given the same `x`, it returns the same output value, which is a function. And, on top of that, the returned function is pure: given the same `y`, it returns the same numeric value. To stress the point

```
let h = g 5
in h 23 == h 23
```

evaluates to `True` since both `h 23` evaluate to `2*5+23`.

By comparison, this evaluates to `False`

```
let h1 = g 5
    h2 = g 1
in h1 23 == h2 23
```

since we compare `2*5+23` against `2*1+23`. This, however, does not break purity since `h1` and `h2` are different function values: we are not calling the same function with the same input, and that can indeed produce different results.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not correct.

The lambda function returns the same output for the same input any time it is called, without any other effects.

To do that it does depend on the value of a parameter to the outer function, but that's just a detail.

In different invocations of `count2` there might be used different values for `bTest`. In such situations the two lambda function will be different, yes, but the `bTest` values serve as a hidden implicit input. Still, the same inputs entailing the same output, which is the definition of "pure".